# how to get checkbox values in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i want to set more value to checkbox,how do it? this is my code: from this code only i could get upto 3 value,why? i want to get 5 value.how do it?

```
$results=$watch.",".$thumbnail.",".$name.",".$description.",".$val;
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]" class="addbtn"  value=<?php echo  $results;?>
```

javascript fn:

```
  function chkbox()
  { 
 $('[name^=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {

 var ckballvalue=($(this).val());  

 var latlngStrs = ckballvalue.split(",",5);
 var link = latlngStrs[0];
 var thumbnail = latlngStrs[1];
 var name = latlngStrs[2];
 var description = latlngStrs[3];
 var categ = latlngStrs[4];

 alert(link+thumbnail+name+description+categ);
   }
```

Comment: *id="checkbox[]"*  By specification, IDs must be unique, thus that makes no sense if you have other inputs with the same ID.  Anyway, I suggest clarifying your question a bit, as I have no idea what specifically you're asking between the PHP with no context and the rather interesting JS.

Comment: should `description` and `categ` get the same value ( `latlngStrs[3]` ) or is just an edit problem ?

Comment: Another hint does one of your php variables contains some `"` character? If it does then at the concatenation you won't get all that string in the value attribute but it will get ignored by the browser as being an undefined attribute.

Comment: Also the `id` cant contain `[]` it can only be letters, numbers, underscores and hyphens.

Comment: Perhaps it's because you're only grabbing checked (`:checked`) values when you want *all* of them? It's unclear from your question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your markup is correct and you're using `POST`, then you just grab them from the `$_POST` variable in PHP.

```
$checkedValues = $_POST['checkbox'];
```

This will be an array of all checked values, where 'checkbox' is the name of your input group.

Comment: i am asking how to get in javascript

Comment: only i got link,thumbnail,name values,i can not get description,categ value why?

Answer (score 1):

When a browser posts a form containing checkboxes, it only posts anything for the checkboxes that have been checked. The ones that are unchecked will not be sent at all.

Therefore, if you have five checkboxes, but only three are checked, your PHP $_POST or $_GET array will only contain entries for those three, not the other two.

This will also means that if you're using `name="checkbox[]"` for all your checkboxes, then your array elements will not be numbered as you expect.

Note that this is the way HTML forms work; it's got nothing to do with PHP.

If you want to force it, you could have a hidden field on the form which mirrors the checkbox state using Javascript. This way you'll be certain you'll always get the value posted to you whether it was checked or not.

Or you could just accept the way it works. You may not get the values posted to you if they aren't checked, but their absence is sufficient, as not having those field posted allows you to know that they weren't checked.

You might find it helpful to give your checkboxes explicit array element keys -- ie rather than `name="checkbox[]"`, use `name="checkbox[3]"`. This way they'll always be posted into the right slot in your $_POST array.

Hope that helps.

Comment: i am asking how to get in javascript